# threadpool funtion cant release function

Tags: c, memory, pthreads, threadpool

i am using the threadpool lib from https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include "main.h"
#include "thpool.h"

#define MAX_THREADS 1000      
#define TASK_QUEUE_SIZE 100000
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024 




static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
    return fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
}

void remove_newline(char *line)
{
    int newline_index = strcspn(line, "\n"); // 查找换行符的位置
    line[newline_index] = '\0';              // 用字符串结束符替换换行符
}

int download_file(const char *url, const char *filename)
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return -1;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    fclose(fp);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return (res == CURLE_OK) ? 0 : -1;
}

int generate_random()
{
    // 返回 0 到 99 之间的随机整数
    return rand() % 100;
}

// 添加任务到队列的函数


// 移除字符串中的换行符

// 任务处理函数
    void process_combination(void *arg)
    {
        brute *myStruct = (brute *)arg;
        printf("%s %s\n",myStruct->param1,myStruct->param2);
        free(myStruct);
        return NULL;
    }

unsigned int ip_to_int(const char *ip)
{
    unsigned int a, b, c, d;
    sscanf(ip, "%u.%u.%u.%u", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    return a | (b << 8) | (c << 16) |  (d << 24);
}

void int_to_ip(unsigned int ip, char *dst)
{
    sprintf(dst, "%u.%u.%u.%u", ip & 0xFF, (ip >> 8) & 0xFF, (ip >> 16) & 0xFF, ip >> 24);
}

void process_cidr(const char *cidr, FILE *output_file)
{
    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    unsigned int prefix, start, end;
    sscanf(cidr, "%15[0-9.]/%u", ip, &prefix);
    start = ip_to_int(ip);
    end = start | (0xFFFFFFFF >> prefix);

    for (unsigned int addr = start; addr <= end; addr++)
    {
        char ip_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        int_to_ip(addr, ip_str);
        fprintf(output_file, "%s\n", ip_str);
    }
}

int main()
{
    threadpool thpool = thpool_init(1000);
    while(1){
        printf("开始下载");
        srand(time(NULL));
        char url[1024];
        sprintf(url, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ANQUSEC/passworer/main/%d/index.txt", generate_random());

        if (download_file(url, "index.txt") != 0)
        {
            sleep(1000);
            return;
        }


        // 读取和处理文件
        FILE *fileA, *fileB;
        char lineA[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
        char lineB[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

        fileA = fopen("index.txt", "r");
        fileB = fopen("ip.txt", "r");

        if (fileA == NULL || fileB == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error opening file");
            // 清理资源

            return -1;
        }
        
        while (fgets(lineA, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fileA) != NULL)
        {
            remove_newline(lineA);
            while (fgets(lineB, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fileB) != NULL)
            {
                remove_newline(lineB);
                brute *myStruct = malloc(sizeof(brute));
                if (myStruct == NULL) {
                    exit(-1);
                }
                strcpy(myStruct->param1,lineA);
                strcpy(myStruct->param2,lineB);
                thpool_add_work(thpool, process_combination, (void*)myStruct);

            }
            fseek(fileB, 0, SEEK_SET);
        }
        
        fclose(fileA);
        fclose(fileB);
        thpool_wait(thpool);
        thpool_destroy(thpool);
    
    // 初始化线程池和同步原语
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i want to make it a loop,but i think it just stuck, it dont go into the next loop,where is my problem,the threadpool init method? or the memory release?
i am running on ubuntu 20.4
i compile it by

```
gcc main.c thpool.c -lcurl
```

it can run it with out a while(1) loop
z